# Touchswipe.js not allowing select box to open on desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cant get my select box to work with i enable touchenabled in desktops. Viewing my fiddles you will see when you click on "ARTICLE" the select box will only work if i disable touchenabled for desktop users.

touchenabled:"on" http://jsfiddle.net/y82XD/  (ARTICLE select box will not work)

touchenabled:"off" http://jsfiddle.net/y82XD/3/ (ARTICLE select box works fine)

I am using a script to detect mobile devices and want to enable touchenabled: "on" , when device.mobile is detected. The mobile detection script has a JavaScript Method called device.mobile() that can be used .  So using the below script for the slider , how would i go about incorporating the device.mobile() to set touchenabled:"on" for mobile , while setting touchenabled:"off" for everything else ?

```
            var tpj=jQuery;
            tpj.noConflict();
            tpj(document).ready(function() {
            if (tpj.fn.cssOriginal!=undefined)
                tpj.fn.css = tpj.fn.cssOriginal;
                tpj('#slidebox').services(
                    {
                        width:620,
                        height:460,
                        slideAmount:4,
                        slideSpacing:10,
                        touchenabled:"off",

NEED CODE HERE to enable touchenabled:"on" when device.mobile detected

                        mouseWheel:"off",
                        hoverAlpha:"on",
                        slideshow:3500,
                        hovereffect:"on",
                        callBack:function() { }
                    });
        });
```

Comment: Question is, SHOULD it work on non mobile browsers? Maybe do some detection and only enable it if on a mobile device?

Comment: That was my next question, i am using a script to detect mobile devices and i just checked and the JavaScript Method is called device.mobile() so how could i get that to touchenabled:"on"

Comment: @MShack Ok, I've edited my answer. Let me know if this works, it seems ridiculously simple.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the select box to function by changing the following two options in your slidebox services:

```
touchenabled:"off"
hoverAlpha:"off"
```

Those were previously on. When I turned them off, the parent slidebox div lost its mousedown and touchcancel event listeners.

I don't know enough about this package to understand what implications this might have. But it looked to be doing everything it was doing previously.

If you need to have these options on, then perhaps you could turn them off when this particular page is displayed? Or maybe you could unbind the two listeners that are causing the problems when the page is displayed.

UPDATE:

Ok, after reading your new comments, I'm not sure why this won't work, but it does seem a bit simple, so maybe I still don't understand it 100%.

```
var touchEnabledValue = (device.mobile) ? "on" : "off;
tpj('#slidebox').services(
  {
     width:620,
     height:460,
     slideAmount:4,
     slideSpacing:10,
     touchenabled: touchEnabledValue,
     mouseWheel:"off",
     hoverAlpha: touchEnabledValue,
     slideshow:3500,
     hovereffect:"on",
     callBack:function() { }
}
```

Comment: i edited my post to better describe what i need to do ty